# Need to bind/populate combobox in WPF forms, ideally with value and display

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, combobox

My application for other reasons isn't set up with the MVVM architecture and I'm not able to at this time. The only thing that I need to modify now is a combobox to be populated from the database (it is stored in a OracleDataReader). I would like to just programmatically add items to the combobox from looping through this OracleDataReader, or bind it in some way.

```
Public Sub LoadLocationCombo()
    Dim rs As OracleDataReader
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim lstItems As New ArrayList

    rs = objClsDB.LocationCombo

    dt.Load(rs)

    dt.Columns("description").AllowDBNull = True
    dt.Columns("value_id").AllowDBNull = True
    dt.Columns("description").DefaultValue = ""
    dt.Columns("value_id").DefaultValue = 0

    dr = dt.NewRow

    dr("description") = ""
    dr("value_id") = 0

    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)

    cboLocation.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
    cboLocation.DisplayMemberPath = "description"
    cboLocation.SelectedValuePath = "value_id"

End Sub
```

That is my current method, I'm trying to add a blank row at the top as well. This makes the combo have what looks like multiple rows but Nothing is in the selected value and nothing displays.

**Edit:** If I remove the cboLocation.DisplayMemberPath and .SelectedValuePath then the combobox is filled with a bunch of System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal

Comment: Are you sure your DataTable has data in it at the time it is bound to the ComboBox?

Comment: Yes, I have doublechecked and it for sure does.

Comment: See my most recent edit

Comment: so what's your question or problem?

Comment: If you would like to see whether the first row is added or not change the line dr("description") = "" to dr("description") = "test" and add one more line cblLocation.SelectedIndex = 0. Make sure database returned some rows using dt.Rows.Count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the DefaultView of a DataTable will return an object of type DataView, and DataView does not have properties called "description" or "value_id". That's why nothing is selected, and nothing is displayed.

You might build some list and fill it with the datatable values, for example:

```
Dim listToFillCombo As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    listToFillCombo .Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(CInt(dr("value_id")), dr("description").ToString))
Next
```

Then the comboBox binding

```
cboLocation.ItemsSource = listToFillCombo 
cboLocation.DisplayMemberPath = "Value"
cboLocation.SelectedValuePath = "Key"
```